# Convergence of histograms

Tags: histogram, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Good morning,
I'm interested in the convergence of empirical distribution functions. In particular, let us suppose to have a population with unknown distribution function $ F(x) $ and that I can sequentially draw samples from it. While I collect the samples, I can build a histogram and update it as soon as new samples are drawn. I can transform the related histogram into an empirical distribution function $ F_n(x) $, where $ n $ is the number of samples collected until a given time instant. From the Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality, I know that

$$
\Pr(\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(x) - F(x)| > \epsilon) \leq 2e^{-2 n {\epsilon} ^ 2}
$$

for $ \epsilon > 0 $. If I interpret correctly this result, it provides an upper bound on the probability of having an error higher than $ \epsilon $ approximating $ F(x) $ with $ F_n(x) $. However, this upper bound totally disregard any information retrievable from the samples that I'm collecting. Is there a way to embed this information to have a better upper bound? Thanks to all

Comment: The "information retrievable from the samples" is incorporated in the $F_n(x)$ (if I have understood, then better if you do not use a histogram as an intermediate step).  Unless you know in advance the form of $F(x)$, I do not see how you might expect to use anything further

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there any hypothesis on $ F(x) $ that allows a better upper bound? I do not mean to know the kind of distribution (gaussian, log-normal, ...) but some other kind of hypothesis (for example, sample mean, sample variance, ...)

Comment: There may be a distinction between $F(x)$ being continuous or not, but all continuous cases will have the same bound so you may as well assume $F(x)=x$ when $x \in [0,1]$ if it makes things easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that it is better to estimate the Cumulative Distribution Function than the EDF. Then the Kolmogorov-Smirnov theorem applies.

However, even with that change, the answer to your question is no. Think of it this way: there is some monotonic function that transforms your distribution into a uniform distribution (indeed, that is the CDF). If you were sampling from a uniform distribution, you would not expect the values returned to be very informative about the rate of convergence.

Comment: I suspect the empirical distribution function $F_n(x)$ is the estimator of the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$.  Your second point applies whenever $F(x)$ is continuous.